How to combine it into a long string based on the numerical value of the assignment in the group by, from small to large
I have a table, and I want to combine it into a long string based on the numerical value of the assignment in the group by, from small to large.
Here is my dataframe :
df = pd.DataFrame({'RTG_CODE':['RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG0538','RTG350001','RTG350001','RTG350001','RTG353904','RTG353904','RTG353904','RTG353904','RTG353904','RTG373902','RTG373902','RTG373902','Baltic','Baltic','Baltic','RTG407002','RTG407002','RTG407002','RTG407002','RTG407002'],'ELEMENT': ['TM~WCO~BKBK','AY~JHGT~BKBK','AY~EHUY~BKBK','AY~RUYI~BKBK','FT~QQ~BKBK','CM~ROIP~BKBK','CM~PPOI~BKBK','TM~WCO~10030269','AY~SO-3.9-4.9.SOT96SD112~10030269','FT~SG~10030269','TM~WCO~KHKH','AY~HVQFN.SOT617CD35~KHKH','AY~WB-QFN-ADV~KHKH','AY~SG-QFN-5X5~KHKH','FT~3L/F~KHKH','TM~WCO~10030269','AY~HVSON.SOT782HA16~10030269','FT~SG~10030269','TM~WCO~10034140','AY~DHX2QFN-2.4-2.SOT1442AA1~10034140','FT~HM/F~10034140','TM~WCO~KHKH','AY~HVQFN.SOT617CD39~KHKH','AY~WB-QFN-ADV~KHKH','FT~DQ/F~KHKH','FTT~FT0010330035/F~KHKH'],'ASSIGNMENT': [-50,110,120,130,200,300,380,-50,130,200,-50,110,120,130,200,-50,120,200,-50,130,200,-50,120,130,200,250]})

df:

I want to get a column for the merged.
df_output = pd.DataFrame({'RTG_CODE': ['RTG0538','RTG350001','RTG353904','RTG373902','Baltic','RTG407002'],'MERGED': ['TM~WCO~BKBK::AY~JHGT~BKBK::AY~EHUY~BKBK::AY~RUYI~BKBK::FT~QQ~BKBK::CM~ROIP~BKBK::CM~PPOI~BKBK','TM~WCO~10030269::AY~SO-3.9-4.9.SOT96SD112~10030269::FT~SG~10030269','TM~WCO~KHKH::AY~HVQFN.SOT617CD35~KHKH::AY~WB-QFN-ADV~KHKH::AY~SG-QFN-5X5~KHKH::FT~3L/F~KHKH','TM~WCO~10030269::AY~HVSON.SOT782HA16~10030269::FT~SG~10030269','TM~WCO~10034140::AY~DHX2QFN-2.4-2.SOT1442AA1~10034140::FT~HM/F~10034140','TM~WCO~KHKH::AY~HVQFN.SOT617CD39~KHKH::AY~WB-QFN-ADV~KHKH::FT~DQ/F~KHKH::FTT~FT0010330035/F~KHKH']})

my desired output :

Any help would be appreciated!

It looks like you want your strings to be joined by '::', so I think you can try @mozway's improvement on my original suggestion:
df.groupby(['RTG_CODE'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(MERGED=('ELEMENT', '::'.join))

On a toy data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['hey','test','test','hi'], 'col':['a','b','c','d']})

   code col
0   hey   a
1  test   b
2  test   c
3    hi   d

df.groupby(['code'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(MERGED=('col', '::'.join))

Result:
   code MERGED
0   hey      a
1  test   b::c
2    hi      d


thanks for your reply. in your answer, it seems the Assignment value doesn't be considered in the agg. i like to combine them based on the ascending order of Assignment column.

That's a minor variation of it: df.groupby(['RTG_CODE'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(MERGED=('ELEMENT', '::'.join))

df.sort_values(['ASSIGNMENT'],ascending=True).groupby(['RTG_CODE'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(MERGED=('ELEMENT', '::'.join))
